# (HTML,CSS,JS) Trying to add Clickable Dropdown, icon button

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I made "hamburger" icon on my website navigation bar.
I added simple animation JavaScript, it works great.
Now I want the icon to open Clickable Dropdown, I am kinda confused since I am already using script file, and class.

### I am not sure how can i combine two JS code to the same Class, and  how to edit the dropdown links with the original icon bars..

this is my Icon :
HTML:

```html
<div class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction(this)"> 

        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.hamburger {
      cursor: pointer;
      color:#333;
      list-style: none;
      float: right;
      padding: 18px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block; 
}
```

Javascript:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

---

Finally this is the dropdown I am trying to add:

HTML:

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .show {display: block;}
```

Javascript:

```js
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to open dropdown when hamburger menu is clicked?

Comment: yes please, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same function for both elements. I think the main issues is that you make the drop down disappear when clicked outside it. This "outside" includes the hamburger menu icon.

Here is a working example:

```js
// Keep a refernce for dropdown to access it from any function
const dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");

function myFunction() {
  dropdown.classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  // Make sure ".hamburger" or any other class is included so when it is clicked it won't hide the dropdown
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .hamburger')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}

.hamburger>div {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <div class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: that is good , but i want the drop down below the hamburger, and not seperated...

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean but I have updated the code. You can arrange HTML element as you like.

Comment: how do i get rid of the dropdown button, user should simply click the hamburger to get the home,about,contact links

Comment: also the animation i made is not working in your code.

Comment: I edited the code to replace the button with the hamburger menu. Your code did not have any animation. If you include a runnable example I can adjust the code to have animation in it.

Comment: I gave up on the animation, anyway i played lil bit with the code, and now i only have problem with the dropdown list  https://code.sololearn.com/Wte1USyrhNDe/#css

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution, hope it works for you:

```
<style>
  .hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 18px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .bar1, .bar2,.bar3 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .dropbtn:hover,
  .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980b9;
  }

  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  .show {
    display: block;
  }
</style>



<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction()">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
  <!-- <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button> -->
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

  function myFunction() {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown') 
    dropdown.classList.toggle('show')
  }

  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.hamburger')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')
      var i
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i]
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show')
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see I commented out the button, I'm not sure why you would use both, the button and the hamburguer button. Also added some styles to the 'bar; divs, otherwise you didn't see any 'hamburguer'.

Lastly change the thing you are matching on the window event listener to see if it contains the 'hamburger' class.

Comment: thank you that works, now when i click on the hamburger it open the 3 link bar but it does push the whole navigation bar down and show me arrows: http://floomby.io/s/031219/rqdewhnW?a

Comment: So, your body and html have no height and the absolutely positioned element shouldn't make it higher, you need more elements on your website, anyways, you should be able to figure it out with styles from now on. Good luck